# Reflecting on property to get attributes. How to do when they are defined elsewhere?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, instance, propertyinfo

I have a class Bar like this:

```
class Foo : IFoo {
  [Range(0,255)]
  public int? FooProp {get; set}
}

class Bar : IFoo
{
  private Foo foo = new Foo();
  public int? FooProp { get { return foo.FooProp; }
                       set { foo.FooProp= value; } } 
}
```

I need to find the attribute [Range(0,255)] reflecting ONLY on the property Bar.FooProp. I mean, the prop is decorated in the class instance (.. new Foo()) not in the class when I am currently parsing. Infact Bar.FooProp has no attributes

EDIT

I moved attributes on the interface's definition, so what I have to do is parsing the inherited interfaces to find them. I can do that because Bar class must implement IFoo.In this particular case, I'm lucky, but the problem remains when I have no interfaces... I will take note for the next time

```
foreach(PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
  IList<Type> interfaces = property.ReflectedType.GetInterfaces();
  IList<CustomAttributeData> attrList;
  foreach(Type anInterface in interfaces)
  {
    IList<PropertyInfo> props = anInterface.GetProperties();
    foreach(PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
      if(prop.Name.Equals(property.Name))
      { 
        attrList = CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(prop);
        attributes = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(CustomAttributeData attrData in attrList)
        {
            attributes.AppendFormat(ATTR_FORMAT,
                                        GetCustomAttributeFromType(prop));
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation a while back where I had an attribute declared on a method in an interface, and I wanted to get the attribute from a method on a type implementing the interface. For example:

```
interface I {
  [MyAttribute]
  void Method( );
}

class C : I {
  void Method( ) { }
}
```

The code below is used to check all of the interface implemented by the type, see which interface members the given `method` implements (using `GetInterfaceMap`), and returns any attributes on those members. Right before this, I also check if the attribute is present on the method itself.

```
IEnumerable<MyAttribute> interfaceAttributes =
  from i in method.DeclaringType.GetInterfaces( )
  let map = method.DeclaringType.GetInterfaceMap( i )
  let index = GetMethodIndex( map.TargetMethods, method )
  where index >= 0
  let interfaceMethod = map.InterfaceMethods[index]
  from attribute in interfaceMethod.GetCustomAttributes<MyAttribute>( true )
  select attribute;

...

static int GetMethodIndex( MethodInfo[] targetMethods, MethodInfo method ) {
  return targetMethods.IndexOf( target =>
         target.Name == method.Name
      && target.DeclaringType == method.DeclaringType
      && target.ReturnType == method.ReturnType
      && target.GetParameters( ).SequenceEqual( method.GetParameters( ), PIC )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When looking at `FooProp`, there is nothing to identify the existence of a `Foo` (at any point). Perhaps you could add an attribute to identify the `foo` field, and reflect on that (via `FieldInfo.FieldType`)?

Comment: infact, the key is reflecting "inside" the get/set method. I dont know if there's a way to understand the return param is a call to an instance method..

Comment: If you are *inside* the get/set, then you already know the type... just use the known type...?

Comment: mhh...I was thinking to move the attributes the interface definition. So I reflect directly on inherited attribs by interface, not on the implemented properties. Could be right, Marc?

Comment: On the interface would work - but it gets a *little* tricky to resolve when a method / property implements an interface, as there are issues with explicit implementation, generics, etc - it isn't trivial, but can be done.

Comment: Hi Marc, as explained just now (see edit), the interface definition is  richer than before. It works but I'm not very for the future. I mean, now the main goal is to collect all the attributes spreaded around into an only ONE *buddy* partial Bar class. For two reasons: xVal validation framework needs it and all the UI hints can drive codesmith to build my views (textboxes, edit areas, ecc)